# Specific scheduler’s threads for tasks each task should have its own scheduler’s thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I'd like to make specific scheduler’s threads for tasks so that each task should have its own scheduler’s thread. How we could achieve this?

- subject_1.onNext(task) -> Emit Task_1 on Scheduler's thread-1
- subject_1.onNext(task) -> Emit Task_2 on Scheduler's thread-2

When work is finished, emit the task and receive it on the same Scheduler's thread.

- subject_1.filter(task) -> Starts working with Task_1 on Scheduler's thread-1
- subject_1.filter(task) -> Starts working Task_2 on Scheduler's thread-2

Pseudo code:

```
// Filter a task A on a Task-1-Thread, filter a task B on a Task-2-Thread, and so on..
return Single
        .just(task)
        .doOnNext { subject_1.onNext(task) } // Emit a task A on a caller's thread
        .observeOn(scheduler)
        .flatMap {
            subject_2
                    // Received on Task-{x}-Thread
                    .filter { doSomeStuff() } <- Release Task-{x}-Thread

subject_1
  .flatmap {}
  .observeOn(scheduler)
  .doOnNext { subject_2.onNext(task) } // Emit a task A on task a specific thread: Task-{x}-Thread
  .subscribe()
```

I am looking for something like this:

Single.just(task).observeOn(printingScheduler, task)

Comment: @dano, yes. I somehow missed that. Thanks! Though, it seems that I cannot accept your answer because it's in the comments section?

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`Schedulers.newThread()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#newThread--):

> Returns a default, shared Scheduler instance that creates a new Thread for each unit of work.